# Translating text in Microsoft translator removes //

Tags: python-3.x, translation, python-3.7, translate, azure-cognitive-services

I am trying to translate a code file and I see the below issues with Microsoft translator

1. Translating below text 
   // 行番号削除正常終
   Gives output 
   Line number deletion successful end
   where it removes the //(double slash)
2. Translating below text 
   System.out.println("【○】COBOL
   Gives output 
   System.out.println_○*○* COBOL

Where the special characters are removed and replaced with some other.

I am reading my file using CP932 encoding and writing using UTF-8.

Please let me know if there are any ideas on how to resolve this issue.

I have tried Google translate and it works well on the same encodings.

Comment: Can you please add more details about the  "to" language that you are trying to translate?

Comment: I am  translating this text to "en"(English).

Comment: please raise a user voice request here (cognitive.uservoice.com/forums/558796-translator-api) for the same.